# returning items in a date range in sql

Tags: mysql

I want to return a row for every month in a range specified- what I'm having trouble with is- that if I do not have a row there is nothing returned; What i was want is the month name to  be returned and winner_id to be null

my query so far.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(dated) as Month, winner_id FROM competitions WHERE dated > '2012-01-01'
```

What i want my output to look like is

```
Month     Winner_id
-------------------
January   NULL
February  2654
March     19864
April     NULL
```

the problem is i do not have a row for january or april in the db- but i still want a month returned?

should i do the months in php and do individual queries for each month?

Comment: What if result contains data from several years?

Comment: the competition is running monthly for the next 6 months- wont contain any data of more than a year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to do this in MySql but it would be overkill in your case. I'd use a variation of your current query and fill the gaps in php:

```
$res = mysql_query( "SELECT MONTH(dated) as month, winner_id".
                    " FROM competitions WHERE dated > '2012-01-01'");
$months = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 6; ++$i) $month[$i] = 0;
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $month[$r['month']] = $r['winner_id'];
}
...
```

Comment: this is the method i ended up using

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a custom column for all months:

Try with below:

```
  SELECT a,c.Winner_id 
  FROM
   (
    select 'January' as a union all select 'Febuary' union all select 'March'
    union all select 'April' union all select 'May' union all select 'June' union all
    select 'July' union all select 'August' union all select 'September' union all 
    select 'October' union all select 'November' union all select 'December'
    ) as a 
  LEFT JOIN competitions  as c on a.a=monthname(c.dated) 
  WHERE  c.dated > '2012-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary table with numbers for six months (or just use a SELECT query with UNIONs) -

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE months(m INT);
INSERT INTO months VALUE (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);

Then join your table to this temp. table, e.g. -

```
SELECT t1.m Month, c.winner_id FROM
  (SELECT @m:=MONTH('2012-01-01') + m, IF(@m > 12, @m - 12, @m) m FROM months) t1
  LEFT JOIN competitions c
    ON t1.m = c.MONTH(dated)
WHERE c.dated > '2012-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if in MySQL there is function that return list of all months. So eventually if any month is missing in your table then its month name can not be fetched at run time. Either you might have to pass months from the script and fetch records accordingly.